# printing a double quote in Haskell

Tags: haskell, formatting, quotes

How does one print quotes in haskell? I would think it is

```
putStrLn "\""
```

but it is not :( I know it's a simple question, but I can't find it anywhere.

To clarify, the result should be simply: `"`
Thanks

Comment: What problems are there with your code? When I paste it into ghci, it prints a double quote, as expected.

Comment: OOps, actually it is.. I just had a typo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want to print a single double quote, you can use `putChar`, like so:

```
putChar '"'
```

Keep in mind that this will not append a newline or anything else like that. If you want to print a quote with a newline, the code you have supplied should be correct.

```
putStrLn "\""
```

should work. The reason for the backslash is that double quotes are used to end strings, so we need to tell the compiler to treat this particular double quote specially – we do that with a backslash.

The combination of a backslash and a character is usually called an "escape sequence" – we have others like `\n` for a newline, `\t` for a tab character and `\\` for an actual backslash. This of course means that you can print a double quote followed by a newline by combining two `putChar`s into

```
putChar '"' >> putChar '\n'
```

where `>>` is the operator to chain two printing operations together. However, doing this is a little weird when you can just do `putStrLn "\""` instead.